# Why does my MUI Grid get squashed when 1 item is removed?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

If my grid has 2 items, it fills the container horizontally. But when one item is removed, particularly the second one, it gets squashed. I can't in my right mind figure out why that would happen. Here's an illustration.

[image]
[image]

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="email"
                  label="Email Address"
                  name="email"
                  value={email}
                  autoComplete="email"
                  onChange={event => setEmail(event.target.value)}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  name="password"
                  label="Test Field Only"
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  value={password}
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                  onChange={event => setPassword(event.target.value)}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: That's strange.  I don't get that behavior when duplicating your code.  I'm guessing here, but it appears that the grid container is having its width controlled by a parent.  Does setting the width of the grid container to a static value solve things?

Comment: The `<Container` is `<Container maxWidth="xs" sx={{ marginTop: 10 }}>`. But I am not sure why removing 1 grid item is the problem, otherwise its absolutely fine.